# Why all click events for checkboxes is called although I clicked only one checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I checked only one checkbox but another click listeners attached to other checkboxes are invoked. I don't think this is a typical case of event bubbling.
How do I solve this issue?

I already checked if this is related to event bubbling. But I don't think so because my input tags are horizontal.

Popup.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Input game title to search metacritic score!</h3><br>
      <p>Press the "Enter" key inside the input field to trigger the button.</p>
      <input id="gameTitle" value="Example : &quot;Gears 5&quot;">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Pc" id="pcCheck">PC<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Ps4" id="ps4Check">PS4<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Xbox" id="xboxCheck">XBOX<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="Switch" id="switchCheck">SWITCH<br>
      <button id="confirmBtn">Confirm</button>
    <p id = "content"></p>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup.js

```
var dict = {};
dict["confirmBtn"] = document.getElementById("confirmBtn");
dict["pcCheck"] = document.getElementById("pcCheck");
dict["ps4Check"] = document.getElementById("ps4Check");
dict["xboxCheck"] = document.getElementById("xboxCheck");
dict["switchCheck"] = document.getElementById("switchCheck");

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 dict["confirmBtn"].addEventListener("click", confirmBtnEvent);
 dict["pcCheck"].addEventListener("click", CheckEvent("pcCheck"),{capture:true});
 dict["ps4Check"].addEventListener("click", CheckEvent("ps4Check"),{capture:true});
 dict["xboxCheck"].addEventListener("click", CheckEvent("xboxCheck"),{capture:true});
 dict["switchCheck"].addEventListener("click", CheckEvent("switchCheck"),{capture:true});
});
```

I want one specific event listener to be called when the corresponding checkbox is clicked.

Comment: addEventListener second argument needs to be a function, not the result of calling a function - unless `CheckEvent(.....)` returns a function ... what is `CheckEvent` function?

Comment: please note: your `<input>` elements are not valid HTML, they are self closing

Comment: `{capture: true}` should be an argument to `addEventListener`, not `CheckEvent`

Comment: `dict[x].id` is the same as just `x`, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `addEventListener` correctly. The argument should be a function reference, not the result of calling the function. And the options need to be an argument to `addEventListener`.

```
dict["pcCheck"].addEventListener("click", function() {
    CheckEvent("pcCheck");
},{capture:true});
```

However, if you change `CheckEvent` slightly, you can simplify it to:

```
dict["pcCheck"].addEventListener("click", CheckEvent, {capture:true});
```

When an event listener is called, `this` is set to the target of the event, so you can just use `this` inside the function, rather than calling `document.getElementById()` with the argument.

Comment: The problem is solved thanks to you. But I have additional questions. So why all click events for checkboxes are called in previous code that  I passed the value in the second parameter of addEventListener?

Comment: When you write `func1(func2(...))` it means to call `func2(...)` immediately, then call `func1()` with the returned value as the argument. So if you write `addEventListener("click", CheckEvent(...))`, it calls `CheckEvent(...)` immediately, then calls `addEventListener()`.